# OptimiseWarning Non-linear (gaussian) data fitting

Tags: python, gaussian, nonlinear-optimization

I'm try to fit data to a gaussian with 3 peaks. I've plotted a graph with my guessed data, however when I try to do the optimisation, it gives me an OptimizeWarning error. Do you know what it could be please? I am a beginner!

````
popt,pcov=curve_fit(multiGauss,wavenumber_T3,Intensity_T3,gP)
yfit_T4=popt[0]*np.exp(-((wavenumber_T3-popt[1])/popt[6])**2)+popt[2]*np.exp(-((wavenumber_T3-popt[3])/popt[6])**2)+popt[4]*np.exp(-((wavenumber_T3-popt[5])/popt[6])**2)

#Plot the data and line of best fit
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.scatter(wavenumber_T3,Intensity_T3,s=60,c='#D9514E',alpha=0.6,label='Data')
plt.plot(wavenumber_T3,yfit_T4,lw=3,c='#2A2B2D',label='Fit')

#add axis labels and a plot legend, and make the font larger
plt.xlabel('Wavenumber / cm$^{-1}$',fontsize=18) 
plt.ylabel('Intensity / a.u.',fontsize=18)
plt.tick_params(labelsize=14)
plt.legend(frameon=False,fontsize=16)

plt.show()```

id=1DUdRamjYLluSz45lRH1f6K0BtBrmWck4[data available here][1]
-------
this is the error:
local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:808: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  category=OptimizeWarning)


  [1]: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DUdRamjYLluSz45lRH1f6K0BtBrmWck4
````

Comment: It is hard to help with a complicated answer and no running code. Can you produce some data to go with your code? In particular, can you provide your imports, etc.?

Comment: Hi - I've uploaded it, thank you!

Comment: You have 5 unknown's at the top of your code. You haven't defined any of them or shown where you import them from. Likewise, placing a link to a google sheet to your data is far from making the data copy and paste-able. Define wavenumber_T3 and Intensity_T3 as lists of a subset of your data. Also define gP, multiGaus, and curve_fit. One should be able to copy and paste your code and produce the result you are getting and have a question about.